# Docker login fails intermittently in GitHub Actions workflow when GHCR image is used

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, docker-registry, ghcr

I'm trying to run a GitHub Actions workflow in a container as shown below.

```
name: My Workflow
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  container-test-job:
    runs-on: [selfhosted]
    container:
      image: ghcr.io/myorg/myrepo/node:18
    steps:
      - name: Echo
        run: echo "Hello"
```

During 'Initialize container' step, it is trying to login to GHCR, I believe it is using GITHUB_TOKEN in the backend to authenticate. But the login is failing with below error and it is happening intermittently and I'm not able to reproduce it on-demand.

`Docker login for 'ghcr.io' failed with exit code 1`

I tired to check the daemon logs and I found below errors in logs.

`level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \https://ghcr.io/v2/\: remote error: tls: internal error"`

`level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/auth returned error: Get \https://ghcr.io/v2/\: remote error: tls: internal error"`

What does these errors mean? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try pulling in that image directly on your self-hosted runner? Does that work after logging into to GHCR?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to login to GHCR on the server directly and pull the image. And this error is occurring intermittently like ~20% of the time in workflows.